# Project compiles if I choose Product Run but I get compile errors if I choose Product Profile

Tags: xcode

I'm not sure how this is possible. I am building an OS X application. This applications builds and run just fine when I compile it by choosing Run but I get the following linker errors when I choose Product->Profile

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"void ByteString::readNextTo<unsigned short>(unsigned short&)", referenced from:
  CommandPacket::readNextCommandTo(Command&) in Command.o
"void ByteString::append<unsigned short>(unsigned short const&)", referenced from:
  TelemetryPacket::setSAS(int) in Telemetry.o
"void ByteString::readAtTo<unsigned char>(unsigned short, unsigned char&)", referenced from:
 etc
```

This is referring to a file Packet.cpp and Packet.hpp which are C++ files. These files are found successfully by the project when I compile normally. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that Xcode was trying too hard to optimize the Release product. In doing so it was ignoring a dummy function which was initializing the use of templates in on of the libraries I was using. This function was not being called by anyone and so it was not getting compiled. I solved this by reducing the "Optimization Level" under Build Settings from the default "Fastest, Smallest [-Os]" to "Fast [-O, O1]". That solved the issue! I imagine it might also be possible to change the code in the library to solve this problem.